# Как заставить TypeScript выбрать правильную сигнатуру метода?

Tags: node.js, typescript, полиморфизм

Экспериментирую с методом [parallelLimit()](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#parallelLimit) из библиотеки [**async**](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/), имеющему несколько сигнатур, которые зависят от того, передан ли третий аргумент, или нет, и в JS всё с ней замечательно:

```js
const { parallelLimit } = async

new Promise(async () => {
  const tasks = Array(10)
    .fill(null)
    .map((item, i) => async () => i)
  const limit = 5
  await parallelLimit(tasks, limit)
    .then((results) => console.log(results.join(',')))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/3.2.3/async.js"></script>
```

[Интерпретация на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Artyom_Ionash/px913nja/49/)

Пытаюсь использовать её же в TypeScript:

> npm i --save-dev @types/async

Но TypeScript не выбирает [правильную](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5ce1902fe161773d90381a636e4623583979c00b/types/async/index.d.ts#L334) сигнатуру, предполагая, что метод вернёт `void`:

> Свойство "then" не существует в типе "void".ts(2339)

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: какие сигнатуры для этой функции в ts указаны?

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/59165
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/59166/files
хотя parallelLimit там не чинят

Comment: @Grundy Если нет третьего аргумента, вернуть `Promise<R>`:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/async/index.d.ts#L332:L334

Comment: да, проблема в том, что `R` тип неоткуда вывести, поэтому тайпскрипт просто не может определить, что ты вызываешь метод с двумя параметрами, а не метод с тремя параметрами, в котором третий - необязательный

Comment: @Grundy Но тут дело будто бы не только в этом, т.к. даже `await parallelLimit<any, number[], any>(tasks, limit)` не отрабатывает, а просто прерывает работу скрипта.

Comment: @АртёмИонаш, что значит _прерывает работу_? Проблема с типами, только до компиляции происходит

Comment: @Grundy По всей видимости происходит какое-то внутреннее необработанное исключение, которое мне не удаётся пока отловить. Исполнение скрипта просто прерывается без всяких дополнительных уведомлений при попытке подать на `await` на `Promise`, который возвращает `parallelLimit(tasks, limit)`.

Comment: @АртёмИонаш, почему ты думаешь, что оно прерывается? Есть ли ошибки в консоли?

Comment: @Grundy В консоль ничего не выводилось. Оказалось, что это какая-то проблема с конфигурацией `tsconfig.json`. Удалил её - всё заработало нормально. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно в вашем случае надо указать передаваемые типы для `parallelLimit`.

```
import { parallelLimit } from 'async';

new Promise(async () => {
  const tasks = Array(10)
    .fill(null)
    .map((item, i) => async () => i)
  const limit = 5
  await parallelLimit<number, number[], Error>(tasks, limit)
    .then((results) => console.log({ results }))
})
```

Comment: Но в таком виде оно не работает. Даже `await parallelLimit<any, number[], any>(tasks, limit)` не отрабатывает, разве нет?

Comment: Сигнатура метода выбирается правильно. Остальное - ваш код, который я взял из вашего вопроса до того как вы его отредактировали.

Comment: Хотя я мог что-то плохо переписать со скриншота. Но вопрос именно о сигнатуре, а не о исполняемом коде.

Comment: Вы запускали этот скрипт локально? В вашем решении ожидается ведь возвращение `number`, а не  `number[]`. Но даже исправление этой ошибки не помогает.

Comment: Я не проверял работает ли скрипт. Вопрос о выборе сигнатуры метода. Остальное относится к использованию библиотеки async и не важно в рамках данного вопроса.